# Sharing / Extending Controllers in large ASP.net MVC application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

I'm developing a fairly large application.

It's basically an eCommerce app- with other "features" like Forums etc...

The "back office" app will be called "Wokingham"

What I currently have is something like this:
*(we have a naming convention bases on names of trees)*

**MyCompany.Honeysuckle**
Project that contains the Model and Data Access (IRepository etc..) for forums

**MyCompany.Willow**
Models and data access for Products, product search etc...

**MyCompany.Poplar**
Models / data access / services etc.. for Orders

**MyCompany.Juniper**
Customers

All the above are class libraries, that compile into a common /bin/ dir

Wokingham (the admin backend system, mentioned above) will share some functionality with the "public" web app-

For example- in Forums (MyCompany.Honeysuckle) - the public app will have the ability to add a new Question.
This functionality is also available in Wokingham.

My question is when it comes to Controllers of the MVC applications.
There will be (at least) 2 ASP.NET MVC Applications-
A separate one for "Wokingham"

Should I have a **MyCompany.Honeysuckle.Controllers** project? That both the public UI project and Wokingham share.?

Or-
Should there be the **MyCompany.Honeysuckle.Controllers** mentioned above, but then the .Wokingham project *extends* the controllers to perform additional required functionality?

Comment: +1 because I'd like to see some discussion about this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would separate the two controllers, one for front-end operations and one for admin side. The tricky question is where to put the shared operations.

**The short way**: can you just redirect/open new window if an admin user wants to create a new forum post? This would save you lot of time, and is common practice.

**The long way**: if having two pages doing the same thing is necessary, then I would go with separate controller operations and views, but shared CRUD services (model layer). The work is mainly to create the different view.

Generally speaking, you want to keep controller operations as simple as possible, as they are just end-point to web requests. And going through the trouble to abstract similarities between two slightly different controller operations is overkill.

Edit: removed irrelevant suggestions.

Comment: Two MVC applications -due to security, the "public" app will be one one server (farm) the "Wokingham" app will be on internal servers

Comment: Ok, removed irrelevant suggestions. But the rest of it still applies, I hope it's useful to you.